# mysql query items with the largest price increase

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, trending

I have a table 'item_prices' with:

```
resource_id, avg_price, time_stamp, samples
```

Items gets a new average price inserted into the table every day. Old averages are not deleted.

How can I query the 10 items with the highest "percent increase in price" since yesterdays average? I would also like to check that the samples is > 10 to ensure accuracy.

to clarify "percent increase in price":

```
percent_increase = (todays_avg_price - yesterdays_avg_price) / yesterdays_avg_price
```

example

```
resource_id |  avg_price |  time_stamp |  samples

    1           450         1380526003     12
    2           650         1380526002     2
    3           980         1380526001     68

    1           400         1380440003     24
    2           700         1380440002     13
    3           400         1380440001     38

    1           900         1380300003     11
    2           250         1380300002     8
    3           300         1380300001     4
```

returns

```
resource id  |  percent_increase

     3              1.45    
     1              0.125
```

Comment: Please, provide some data and sample of desired result

Comment: ok, updated with an example.

Comment: Can you provide the schema for the table?

Comment: all the rows are INT(15)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select  
today.resource_id, 
(today.avg_price - yesterday.avg_price) / yesterday.avg_price as percent_increase
from 
item_prices today, 
item_prices yesterday
where today.resource_id = yesterday_resource_id
and   DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(today.timestamp)) = $today
and   DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(yesterday.timestamp)) = $yesterday
order by percent_increase desc 
limit 10
```

This is a self join; apologies for the archaic join syntax, it's a bad habit I find hard to shake.

Comment: Ok Neveille thats really helpfull! What do I replace $today and $yesterday with?  also im not sure if this matters but the timestamps for each day arent all the same, but they're within a 10 minute window

Comment: got it working! I used: and   today.timestamp > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 85400

Answer (score -1):

Please try the query below..

```
  select top 1 resource_id,avg_price from item_Prices 
  group by resource_id,avg_price
  having count(resource_id,avg_price)>
  10 order by time_stamp
```

Comment: He is using MySQL. Top 1 I believe is MSSQL syntax.